# Dynamic column names in the Postgres query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I have one table with a bunch of fields. For simplicity, assume 5 fields:

```
unique_id, currency_name, stock_description, company_name, city_name
```

say, the sample values are:

```
INTQL123, USD,  "INT Stock", "International Stock Corporation", "CHICAGO"
```

And another one called **override_table** that can contain the override values for any column:

```
unique_id, override_column, override_value
```

Sample values:

```
INTQL123, "city_name", "NEW YORK"
```

So it is overriding the value of the city "CHICAGO" with the new value "NEW YORK"

I want to be able to write an SQL UPDATE statement with such dynamic column names. We can assume they will only be of the varchar type. Any idea?

Comment: You don't appear to be changing any column names in your example, just replacing a value where the IDs match. 1. Is it just the "override_column" that you are referring to as dynamic, and 2. Can you have more than one override for each unique_id ?

Comment: Are you using both Postgresql 9.4 _and_ 9.5?

Comment: SELECT version();  --> Postgres 14.5

Comment: @RichardHuxton I have a very simple use case. I just need to know how I can refer to the column name dynamically. I.e., 
```
update common_table CT
set column = {column_name} from override_table
where id = CT.id

Answer (score 1):

Yoy can achieve this with an anonymous PL/pgSQL block and dynamic SQL.

```sql
do language plpgsql
$$
declare
  r record;
  DYNSQL constant text := 'UPDATE the_table SET %I = %L WHERE unique_id = %L';
begin
  for r in select * from override_table loop
    execute format(DYNSQL, r.override_column, r.override_value, r.unique_id);
  end loop;
end;
$$;
```

The code above is SQLi prone. Make sure that no malicious values exist in table `override_table` before running it.

**Edit**
"is there a way to return the number of updates back to the caller?"
Anonymous `do` blocks do not return anything. Two approaches come to my mind.

- You can shape the code above as a function with a counter, say `dyn_update`, and issue `select dyn_update()` from Java;

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dyn_update()
returns integer language plpgsql as
$$
declare
  r record;
  DYNSQL constant text := 'UPDATE the_table SET %I = %L WHERE unique_id = %L';
  retval integer := 0;
begin
  for r in select * from override_table loop
    execute format(DYNSQL, r.override_column, r.override_value, r.unique_id);
    retval := retval + 1;
  end loop;
  return retval;
end;
$$;
```

- `select count(*) from override_table` as it would return exactly the number of updates (unless the do block bangs an exception)

Comment: OK, I will try it. Is this the only option?

Comment: Well, for sure there should be others that do not come to my mind.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works like a charm. One question: is there a way to return the number of updates back to the caller? I execute this from Java via JDBC (preparedStatement.executeUpdate()) and would like to ideally capture how many records have been updated with this query. Currently, preparedStatement.executeUpdate() returns 0 even though it updates the database as expected.